# Meaning of `pop` when referring to bits

Tags: c, gcc, bit

Taking a look at [GCC's builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html), I noticed the use of the string `pop` in function name (`__builtin_popcount`), etc. I've also seen other references to pop in other implementations.

When referring to set bits, why is `pop` used, and what does it mean?

Comment: It's short for "population" (i.e., the number of bits that are "populated" by being set to 1)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage You should put that in an  answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's short for "population" (i.e., the number of bits that are "populated" by being set to 1), and is also known as the *Hamming weight*.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight):

> The Hamming weight of a string is the number of symbols that are different from the zero-symbol of the alphabet used. It is thus equivalent to the Hamming distance from the all-zero string of the same length. For the most typical case, a string of bits, this is the number of 1's in the string. In this binary case, it is also called the **population count**, **popcount** or sideways sum. It is the digit sum of the binary representation of a given number and the ℓ₁ norm of a bit vector.